# Capturing nested expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse expressions such as `(1 < 2 ? foo : bar)` in JavaScript (similar to shorthand if-then-else expressions) to extract the condition-part (`1 < 2`), the then-part (`foo`) and the else-part (`bar`). I am using a regular expression which works fine for simple expressions, but when I am trying to parse nested expressions, the regex fails.

Regex: `/\((.*)\?([^:]*)(:.*)?\)/`

Simple example:

```
/\((.*)\?([^:]*)(:.*)?\)/.exec('dsa dsadsa dsa(1 < 2 ? foo : bar) dsa dsa dsa')

0: "(1 < 2 ? foo : bar)"
1: "1 < 2 "
2: " foo "
3: ": bar"
```

Nested example (`(H < 12 ? (m > 30 ? foo : bar) : baz))`):

```
/\((.*)\?([^:]*)(:.*)?\)/.exec('dsa dsadsa dsa(H < 12 ? (m > 30 ? foo : bar) : baz)) dsa dsa dsa')
0: "(H < 12 ? (m > 30 ? foo : bar) : baz))"
1: "H < 12 ? (m > 30 "
2: " foo "
3: ": bar) : baz)"
```

What I really want as result of the nested example is

```
1: "H < 12"
2: "(m > 30 ? foo : bar)"
3: ": baz"
```

but the regular expression isn't respecting the nested structure of the expression. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Afaik, you can't capture recursive targets using just the one regex.

Comment: I don't want to capture all recursive targets. I just want the regex to keep the nested targets together (see the difference between actual and expected in the targets it returned for the nested example). The target `(m > 30 ? foo : bar)` will be parsed again with the same regex in a subsequent (recursive) step, but for that to happen it shouldn't be split in the way it is.

Comment: What's the point, are you going to `eval()` those Strings?

Comment: Doesn't matter. It's still a recursive target. You have parenthesis pairs that *might* contain more parenthesis pairs. There isn't a way for regex to know how they match up unless you can guarantee they're always ordered in a certain way.

Comment: @StackSlave no, I'm not. it just looks similar to JavaScript, but it isn't

Comment: Javascript regex doesn't allow recursive matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do it all in one pass using regex but you could start from the most nested matches and then work your way outward in layers.

I've changed the regex to only match the most nested match(s) and then, once their data is read, I remove the matches from the `str` and run the regex again to get the next most nested layer and repeat until all layers have been read.

```js
let str = 'dsa dsadsa dsa(H < 12 ? (m > 30 ? foo : bar) : baz)) dsa dsa dsa';
const regex = /\(([^?]+)\?([^:()]*):([^()]+)?\)/;

const list = [];
let matches = regex.exec(str);
let loopLimit = 1000;
while (matches) {
  if (loopLimit-- <= 0) throw 'loopLimit exhausted';
  str = str.replace(matches[0], `~list[${list.length}]~`);
  list.push(matches);
  
  matches = regex.exec(str);
}

console.log(list);
for (let item of list) {
  console.log(item[1]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try with

```
\((.*?)\?(\(?.*\)?)?:(\(?.*\)?)?\)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mxADOu/1)